# Order joined table with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I wrote a query with doctrine where I have joined fruits and vitamins table.

I have sorted vitamins by name ASC but I need to do the same thing with joined table.

I tried

> addOrderBy()

, but no luck..

Note: **'c'** is Vitamins table.

Everything is returned as it should except fruits are returned with no order..

My code:

```
 $queryBuilder =  $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c', 'ct.name AS fruitName', 'ct.id AS fruitId')
        ->join('App\Entity\Fruits', 'ct', Expr\Join::WITH, 'ct.id = c.fruitName')
        ->orderBy('c.name');

    $fruits = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    $structure = [];
    foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
        $structure[$fruit['fruitName']][] = $fruit[0];
    }
    return $structure;
```

Comment: Is `$fruits` ordered in the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these:

**Option 1:**

```
$qb->orderBy('c.name ASC, ct.name ASC');
```

**Option 2:**

```
$qb->addOrderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
   ->addOrderBy('ct.name', 'ASC')
```